# How to do simple csv file COPY in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, csv

I have:

```
TAG_ID,TAGNAME,HH_INCEPT,ACCOUNTNUMBER,ACCT_START_DATE,ACCT_STOP_DATE,ORION_CLIENT_TRAIL
45298,JIM JONES,11/16/07,905413871,11/16/07,8/15/14,
```

My create table:

```
CREATE TABLE folio_groups
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  tag_id integer NOT NULL,
  tagname character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  hh_incept date NOT NULL,
  accountnumber character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  acct_start_date date NOT NULL,
  acct_stop_date date,
  orion_client_trail integer
)
```

And I try:

```
# COPY folio_groups FROM '/tmp/folio.csv' CSV HEADER;
```

But get:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "JIM JONE"
CONTEXT:  COPY folio_groups, line 2, column tag_id: "JIM JONE"
```

Any idea how to copy this simple CSV?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
COPY folio_groups (
  tag_id,
  tagname,
  hh_incept_date,
  accountnumber,
  acct_start_date,
  acct_stop_date,
  orion_client_trail
)
FROM '/tmp/folio.csv' CSV HEADER;
```